# Can't figure out how to solve this using Local Storage and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage, object-literal

I am creating a web application to create, edit, delete and view cases. All this has to be stored in local storage, and I'm only allowed to use JS and jQuery.

My problem is how can I click on an already created case, to redirect to a page with more info about that case? I've tried to look it up online, but nothing seems relevant.

This is the create new case page, which pushes the cases to another site:

```js
let caseList = [];

const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit-btn");
const title = document.getElementById("title");
const desc = document.getElementById("desc");

const newCase = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let cases = {
    title: title.value,
    desc: desc.value,
    type: $("#type option:selected").text() + ".png",
    area: $("#area option:selected").text(),
  };

  caseList.push(cases);
  document.forms[0].reset();

  localStorage.setItem("caseList", JSON.stringify(caseList));
  alert("Sak opprettet");
  return true;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  submitBtn.addEventListener("click", newCase);
});
```

Here's the site which outputs the cases. From here I want to click on an already created case to get more info on another page:

```js
const mainContainerGrid = document.getElementById('main-container-grid');

mainContainerGrid.innerHTML = localStorage.length;
if (localStorage.length > 0) {
  let addCase1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("caseList"));

  let html = "";
  addCase1.forEach(case1 => {
    html += `<div class="case1">
      <img class="img" src="/images/${case1.type}" >
      <h1>${case1.title}</h1>
      <button class="show-more">Les mer</button>
    </div>`
  });
  mainContainerGrid.innerHTML = html;
} else {
  mainContainerGrid.innerHTML = "No cases created"
};
```

Here's how my local storage is set up:

[image: Here's how my local storage is set up]

Comment: You need to clarify your usage of the words **page** and **sites**.

Answer (score 0):

Value is stored as string in localStorage. You mau need to use `JSON.parse` to get as array

`mainContainerGrid.innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('caseList'))length;`

Comment: I am storing it as parse, just some code lines above.